# How to speed up async functions in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have created this function in a library. I use this function for both console and WPF app. In my console app, this function finishes in less than a second with large collection up to 80 items and small collections e.g. 5.

Furthermore, in my WPF app when I run this function with a collection of items up to 80 it takes over a minute to finish executing but items of up to 5 items finish executing in less than a second.

C# Code:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, string[]>> GetTemplates(string showName)
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> d = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    // Get element collection uri of show "DemoShow"
    var elementCollectionUriTask = Task.Run(() => GetElementCollectionUri(vizServiceDocURL, showName));
    var elementCollectionUri = await elementCollectionUriTask;

    var templateCollectionUriTask = Task.Run(() => GetTemplateCollectionUri(elementCollectionUri));
    var templateCollectionUri = await templateCollectionUriTask;

    var templateNamesTask = Task.Run(() => GetListOfTemplateName(templateCollectionUri));
    var templateNames = await templateNamesTask;

    //get the name and links from each show and add them to the dictionary
    foreach (string templateName in templateNames)
    {
        var templateCollectionEntryUriTask = Task.Run(() => GetTemplateCollectionEntryUri(templateCollectionUri, templateName));
        var templateCollectionEntryUri = await templateCollectionEntryUriTask;

        var elementModelUriTask = Task.Run(() => GetTemplateElementModelUri(templateCollectionUri, templateName));
        var elementModelUri = await elementModelUriTask;

        await Task.Run(() => PrintVdfModel(elementModelUri));

        string[] links = new string[2] { templateCollectionEntryUri, elementModelUri };
        d.Add(templateName, links);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: You're thinking that running in Tasks is going to speed things up, you're spinning up method calls in Tasks and awaiting them immediately which is adding more overhead than needed for a method that looks primarily synchronous and sequential. Your foreach loop certainly can have jobs spun up as Tasks then add those Tasks into a List and await all with `await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);` outside the loop, or use `Parallel.ForEach` which **is** a **blocking operation**.

Comment: Agree with @ColinM, you're scheduling up to 80 * 2 essentially sequential operations on the thread pool...where they're likely to have to wait on each other. Just do the work sequentially or write some genuinely async versions of the sync methods you're awaiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, if you want to speed up the processing of these jobs then you certainly can do a bit of work on the loop to have the logic applied in parallel to all template names.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, string[]>> GetTemplates(string showName)
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> d = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    // Get element collection uri of show "DemoShow"
    var elementCollectionUri = GetElementCollectionUri(vizServiceDocURL, showName);

    var templateCollectionUri = GetTemplateCollectionUri(elementCollectionUri);

    var templateNames = GetListOfTemplateName(templateCollectionUri);

    //get the name and links from each show and add them to the dictionary
    // Keep a temporary List of Tasks
    List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string templateName in templateNames)
    {
        string localTemplateName = templateName;
        // Apply our logic and add to our Dictionary in a task
        Task jobTask = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var templateCollectionEntryUri = GetTemplateCollectionEntryUri(templateCollectionUri, localTemplateName);

            var elementModelUri = GetTemplateElementModelUri(templateCollectionUri, localTemplateName);

            string[] links = new string[2] { templateCollectionEntryUri, elementModelUri };
            d.Add(localTemplateName, links);
        });

        // Add the task to our temp collection
        allTasks.Add(jobTask);
    }

    // Wait for all tasks to finish, WhenAll is non-blocking unlike WaitAll.
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: The executing time is still over a minute. could be the way I am invoking it?

 `Dictionary < string, string[]> l = await Task.Run(() => _Viz.GetTemplates("MyShow"));`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, if it's only happening in the WPF app, I'd suggest performance profiling and seeing where the majority of the time is spent.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at the performance profiling. There is no other code because when I did have I created a new WPF app with minimal code. So I just added a button and invoke this method with the code in my previous comment and put a breakpoint a the end of the function.